# CSS3 Animation play/pause with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

i need to have an animation on my website that is able to be paused and continued. I have been trying for hour to get this working and finally got somewhere in pausing just one of the images that need pausing. I cant work out how to pause all images, can anyone help me?

```js
// JavaScript Document
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
var animated = document.getElementsByClassName("animated");
play.addEventListener('click', playAnimation);
pause.addEventListener('click', pauseAnimation);

function playAnimation() {
  for (var i = 0; i < animated.length; i += 1) {
    animated[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    animated[i].style.animationPlayState = "running";
  }
}

function pauseAnimation() {
  for (var i = 0; i < animated.length; i += 1) {
    animated[i].style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
    animated[i].style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
main {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
header {
  height: 75px;
  background: #ebebeb url(img/taylor%20logo.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 150px 47.75px;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url(img/tay1.png);
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url(img/taylor-swift-009.jpg);
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url(img/Taylor-Swift.jpg);
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #fff0fb;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}
footer {
  padding: 20px 5px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  color: #514f4f;
}
footer nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
footer nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
footer nav a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.social:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.social {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
/*****ANIMATION*****/

#animation {
  height: 450px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: url(img/scene.png) fixed no-repeat center;
}
#animation:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
.flash {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(img/spritesheet.png) no-repeat left center;
}
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -100px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -100px;
  }
}
.flash-1 {
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  top: 50px;
  left: 400px;
}
.flash-2 {
  left: 100px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}
.flash-3 {
  left: 350px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
}
.flash-4 {
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 80px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.flash-5 {
  left: 375px;
  bottom: 70px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}
.flash-6 {
  bottom: 100px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .2s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}
.flash-7 {
  bottom: 290px;
  left: 170px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}
.flash-8 {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 200px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
}
.flash-9 {
  bottom: 370px;
  left: 450px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .7s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .7s;
}
.flash-10 {
  bottom: 300px;
  left: 100px;
  animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  animation-delay: .9s;
  -webkit-animation: play .5s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
}
.speech img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: speechFadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: speechFadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.speech {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.speech-1 {
  bottom: 750px;
  left: 420px;
}
.speech-2 {
  bottom: 900px;
  left: 900px;
}
@keyframes speechFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes speechFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes speechFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#taylorCartoon {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 380px;
  left: 820px;
  animation-name: taylorWalk;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: taylorWalk;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes taylorWalk {
  from {
    left: 820px;
  }
  to {
    left: 420px;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes taylorWalk {
  from {
    left: 820px;
  }
  to {
    left: 420px;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes taylorWalk {
  from {
    left: 820px;
  }
  to {
    left: 420px;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
.control {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.playHolder {
  background: url(img/play.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.pauseHolder {
  background: url(img/pause.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
  <title>Taylor Swift</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <header>
      </header>
    </div>
    <main>
      <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="module content">
        <div class="container">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil consequuntur, nesciunt dicta, esse rem ducimus itaque quis. Adipisci ullam nam qui illum debitis sit ad in delectus, repudiandae non dolorum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Suscipit veritatis, facere aliquid itaque tempore consequatur nihil sint enim aliquam id saepe magnam totam repellat placeat a fugit nulla molestias voluptas.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="module parallax parallax-2">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="module content">
        <div class="container">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil consequuntur, nesciunt dicta, esse rem ducimus itaque quis. Adipisci ullam nam qui illum debitis sit ad in delectus, repudiandae non dolorum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Suscipit veritatis, facere aliquid itaque tempore consequatur nihil sint enim aliquam id saepe magnam totam repellat placeat a fugit nulla molestias voluptas.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="module parallax parallax-3">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="module content">
        <div class="container">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil consequuntur, nesciunt dicta, esse rem ducimus itaque quis. Adipisci ullam nam qui illum debitis sit ad in delectus, repudiandae non dolorum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Suscipit veritatis, facere aliquid itaque tempore consequatur nihil sint enim aliquam id saepe magnam totam repellat placeat a fugit nulla molestias voluptas.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      MUSIC VIDEO
      <section class="module content">
        <div class="container">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil consequuntur, nesciunt dicta, esse rem ducimus itaque quis. Adipisci ullam nam qui illum debitis sit ad in delectus, repudiandae non dolorum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Suscipit veritatis, facere aliquid itaque tempore consequatur nihil sint enim aliquam id saepe magnam totam repellat placeat a fugit nulla molestias voluptas.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div id="animation" class="animated">
        <div class="flash flash-1" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-2" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-3" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-4" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-5" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-6" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-7" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-8" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-9" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div class="flash flash-10" class="animated">
        </div>
        <div id="taylorCartoon" class="animated">
          <img src="img/taylor cartoon .png" width="181" height="300" />
        </div>
        <div class="speech speech-1" class="animated">
          <img src="img/SPEECH1.png" width="100" height="99" />
        </div>
        <div class="speech speech-2" class="animated">
          <img src="img/speech2.png" width="100" height="99" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="play">Play</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" id="pause">Pause</button>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="copyright">
        <small>
              &copy; Lana Yaffe 2015 | Taylor Swift
            </small>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="http://http://taylorswift.tumblr.com/">
              <img src="img/Tumblr.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/taylorswift13">
              <img src="img/Twitter.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TaylorSwift">
              <img src="img/Facebook.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://instagram.com/taylorswift/">
              <img src="img/Instagram.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since we're missing the stylesheet, can you make a jsFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i added the styles but here https://jsfiddle.net/y6mgpzke/

Comment: It works fine for me (even without user86745458's fix). I see a box move to the side (images aren't loading) and if I press pause it stops moving.

Comment: thats what i mean i cant seem to find the issue, only seems to paul the woman moving across the screen for mee but need the flashes and speach bubbles to stop too

Answer (score 0):

If you want all animations of class `.animated` to stop running you can do something like:

```
body.pause .animated {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Then do:

```
function pause_all() {
    document.body.className = "pause";
}

function play_all() {
    document.body.className = "";
}
```

I don't know if this works on or not because without the images it's hard to see if the animations work right.

Comment: sorry where would i put that been working a long time getting tired haha